# Original size of image - performance relevant in createjs

Tags: image, performance, size, createjs

When loading images via Bitmap() into the stage/container is it relevant regarding the performance once they are loaded and scaled how big the original images were ?

Say I have some images of 800x800 but in the canvas they are only used at a maxiumum size of 400x400. Would it be better to initially onnly make them 400x400?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the images will become smaller in size, and that is a benefit for your bandwith and performance. Ofcourse the Canvas won't need to scale down the image anymore so the image will be more sharper. Nothing but benefits.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I might have missed saying that the canvas behaves in a responsive way. Meaning it resizes to the screen size of the users device. So I have to resize them anyway. So, besides the higher network load are there downsides regarding the scaling? The biggest occurance of an image might be around 650px width the smallest around 100px.

Comment: No. I am also using Canvas in a responsive way for 50+ games and the biggest images are not bigger than the maximum size of my canvas (1024px). I'm scaling them down and have not seen any issues across browsers and various tablets.